# Joining Two Arrays Together and Counting Unique Id by using Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, laravel, join

I have those two arrays that I added to attachments. 
"PartnerAffiliateCodeId" from first array and "Id" from second array is our primary key. 
"UserAction" must be counted for every unique "PartnerAffiliateCodeId" so in our case it is 5. 
Normally I think this must be done by SQL but unfortunately this is a API method that I am receiving so I have to handle it by PHP.
Any ideas about how I can make such join with PHP using these two arrays?

[image: Arrays]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear on exactly what you're trying to get at with `UserAction`, but you could try something like this:

```
//$array1 = the first array
//$array2 = the second array

array_push($array_1, array(
        "DateTime" => "",
        "HttpReferer" => "",
        "Id" => count($array1),
        "PartnerAffiliateCodeId" => $array2["Id"],
        "UserAction" => "Click"
    ));
```

Comment: Yes, I am also planning it this way. I need to count these "UserAction" if it is click, where "PartnerAffiliateCodeId" is same. 
Kinda like:
Unique "PartnerAffiliateCodeId"
Count "UserAction"

There is no different "PartnerAffiliateCodeId" yet but there will be.

Comment: This seems like what I need but I could not make it work. Also there is a missing anti parenthesis in the end.

Comment: Seem there is no better opinions so to close the post I will accept this one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to match the ID key to the PartnerAffiliateCodeId in your returned data set.
Without knowing your setup, or bothinging with total optimization here a workable solution which will give you some direction.

```
function selectPartnerWhere($id=null; $from=array())
{

  $codes = array();
  foreach($from as $k => $p)
  {
    if($id == $p['PartnerAffiliateCodeId'])
    {
       return $from[$k];
    }
  }

  return array();

}

$theData = //your array above
$thePartner = //your partner above

$partnerData = selectPartnerWhere($thePartner['Id'], $theData);
```